# Selecting data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

1. For example `test` column 7 contains two rows, if the `number` column contains values 5 AND 6, AND the value is NOT  **X** in the `chr` column, I would like to select select the rows with 7 in the `test` column.
2. For example `test` column 10 contains three rows, if the `number` column contains values 5 AND 6, AND the value **X** exists in the `chr` column, I would like to exclude rows with 10 in the `test` column.

The [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f209fe/5) of the below Schema and broken SQL query is available on SQL fiddle.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA (ID INT, TEST INT, CHR VARCHAR(1), NUMBER INT);

INSERT INTO TEST_DATA VALUES 
( 1    ,    7 , 'C'   ,       5),
( 2    ,    7 , 'T'   ,       6),
( 3    ,    8 , 'C'   ,       4),
( 4    ,    8 , 'T'   ,       5),
( 5    ,    9 , 'A'   ,       4),
( 6    ,    9 , 'G'   ,       5),
( 7    ,   10 , 'T'   ,       4),
( 8    ,   10 , 'A'   ,       5),
( 9    ,   10 , 'X'   ,       6),
(10    ,   14 , 'T'   ,       4),
(11    ,   14 , 'G'   ,       5);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_data t1, test_data t2
WHERE t1.number=5 is not t1.chr=X AND
      t2.number=6 is not t2.chr=X;
```

How would it be possible to keep `test` column if `number` columns contains 5 and 6 and the `chr` column does not contain **X**?

**UPDATE** As result it should only be `test` column with 7, because `test` column 7 have 5 and 6 in the `number` column and not X.

**UPDATE 2** Result example:

```
ID | TEST | CHR  |  NUMBER               
1  |  7   |  C   |    5        
2  |  7   |  T   |    6
```

Comment: `the number column contains values 5 AND 6` - this is not possible and would always return an empty result, since the same column in one row can not contain **both** `5` **AND** `6`. You probably mean `OR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly...

```
SELECT a.test 
  FROM test_data a
  LEFT
  JOIN test_data b
    ON b.test = a.test 
   AND b.chr = 'x'
 WHERE a.number IN (5,6)
   AND b.id IS NULL
 GROUP
    BY a.test
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1939f/4

You can join this result back on to `test_data` to get all results with a `test` equal to 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM test_data
WHERE number IN (5,6) 
AND test NOT IN (10)
AND chr NOT IN ('X');
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f209fe/20)

Comment: almost, it should only be `test` column with 7, because `test` column 7 have 5 and 6 in the `number` column and not X.

Comment: @user977828:Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, but 8, 9 and 14 out of `test` column appears in the result. How would it be possible to get only `test` column 7 in a not static way like *AND test NOT IN (8, 9, 10, 14)*?

Comment: @user977828: instead of `test NOT IN (10)`, add `test IN (7)`.

Comment: However, in a big query I would not that e. g. `test` column 7 would fulfill the requirements. Is it a way to do it more dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

[EDIT]

```
select o.*
FROM
test_data o,
(SELECT o.TEST
FROM test_data o
WHERE o.NUMBER = 5) five,
(SELECT o.TEST
FROM test_data o
WHERE o.NUMBER = 6) six
WHERE five.TEST = six.TEST
AND o.TEST = five.TEST
AND o.TEST NOT IN (SELECT distinct TEST FROM test_data WHERE chr = 'X')
```

The result is,

```
ID | TEST | CHR | NUMBER

1   7      C      5 
2   7      T      6
```

Comment: almost, it should only be `test` column with 7, because `test` column 7 have 5 and 6 in the `number` column and not X.

Comment: edited the query... hopefully it matches your expected result... looks ugly though

Answer (score 0):

You want it like this ?

### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM test_data
WHERE ID NOT IN 
(
   SELECT ID 
   FROM test_data 
   WHERE CHR='X' 
   AND NUMBER IN (5,6)
 ) 
 AND NUMBER IN (5,6)
```

### Result

```
ID | TEST | CHR  |  NUMBER               
1  |  7   |  C   |    5        
2  |  7   |  T   |    6     
4  |  8   |  T   |    5  
6  |  9   |  G   |    5  
8  |  10  |  A   |    5  
11 |  14  |  G   |    5
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would it possible to add to the above query to retrieve dynamically only rows with `TEST` column 7, because it has has 5 and 6 in the `number` column and no x?